# Track Mobile Sessions Using Marketing Cloud SDK

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk, mobilepush, session-id, marketingcloudapi

We would like to track user sessions on a customer's app **using the marketing cloud SDK**, but after digging on the internet I haven't find a way to do so.

Is it possible?

Comment: What information do you want to track exactly?

Comment: Mostly Sessions - When is the user using the app and when does he log out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Last Application Open` and `Last Message Open` are part of the Mobile Push data model. You can check the list of all available attributes by going to Data Designer > Mobile Push Data.

From the send reports, you can also have `Time in App` when a Push notification is opened.

But if you are looking for more detailed session data, I would suggest that you extend the Mobile Push data model using custom attributes & tags updated directly from the App using custom code.

Comment: This sounds very helpful, I'll check it out and update if it works، thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using this for MobilePush segmentation and audience, you should use attributes or tags - that should allow you to accomplish mapping your user's "profile" state to something in Marketing Cloud (if, of course, you are using the MobilePush SDK).